# event to handle on changing tabs to resize div

Tags: jquery, tabs, focus

I have a page with multiple tabs set up with links that have corresponding divs which are displayed when the tab is clicked.  I have different sized divs on each tab, and I want the parent container to change size with its content as I change tabs.  I can't seem to find the right event to hook into, focus isn't firing reliably, blur fires when I select the tab (why???) and click fires when I select the tab as well, before the inner div has a width I can check to modify the parent div.

Is there a better event to use, or a better way to do this entirely?

Comment: Please show your code, as well as an image showing what you want to happen. Ideally, post your code as a jsfiddle so we can test and modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the event I was looking for was the tabsshow event http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/. This event let me change the width of the parent div after the tab loads, giving me access to the new child's width.